# Gatsby x Strapi - image gallery fine in dev but ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error in build

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi

I have an issue where a gallery from strapi upload folder loads totally fine in dev but as soon as its built i get the broken link icon. Even though the src is totally correct. In the console log i get 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' for all the images.

Code -

```
<div className="image-grid">
                {data.home.galleryImage.map((image, index, caption) => (
                      <div className="image-item" key={`${index}-cl`} class="imgcontt">
                       <img src={`http://167.99.84.214${image.url}`} alt="hh" class="galleryimg" thumbnail/>
                      </div>
                ))  
                }
                </div>
```

Query -

```
export const query = graphql`
  query GetSingleHome($slug: String) {
 galleryImage {
      url
      caption
    }
}
`
```

Comment: Are you using Docker?

Comment: No, should i be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your issue appears due to the changing port between `gatsby develop` (port `8000`) and `gatsby build` (port `9000`). Since the requesting port has changed it causes the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` because of the `src` of the `<img>` tag.

I would suggest using [`gatsby-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/working-with-images/) for handling and bypassing that type of issues. Your code should look like this:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query GetSingleHome($slug: String) {
    galleryImage { 
      formats {
        medium
          childImageSharp {
           fluid(maxWidth: 400, maxHeight: 250) {
             ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

*Note: I'm assuming that you've set properly the filesystem ([`gatsby-source-filesystem`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-filesystem/)) in order to allow Gatsby to parse and compile your images. If not, please configure it properly. Change the `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` as you wish.*

Now, you can use:

```
 <div className="image-grid">
    {data.home.galleryImage.map((image, index, caption) => (
          <div className="image-item" key={`${index}-cl`} class="imgcontt">
           <Img fluid={image.formats.medium.childImageSharp.fluid} alt="hh" class="galleryimg" thumbnail/>
          </div>
    ))  
    }
    </div>
```

Managing images with `gatsby-image` allowing you to create local GraphQL nodes for the images, avoiding that connection issues.

If you haven't set your filesystem:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `pages`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/images/`, //path to your images
  },
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 

Ive implemented the above but get "error    Cannot query field "childImageSharp" on type "StrapiHomesGalleryImage"  ". I read somewhere this may be to do with the fact there are multiple images in galleryImage?

Comment: realised from graphgiql they are reference-able by -  galleryImage {
      formats {
        medium {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }

Comment: how should i adjust your code above to get it out of that query?

Comment: I've updated the answer. It's just a nested object so you need to access the child properties. The same for the GraphQL query.

Comment: i thought so but it still throws an error - 194:11  error    Cannot query field "childImageSharp" on type "StrapiHomesGalleryImageFormats"  graphql/template-strings

Comment: As I said, I've assumed that you've set your filesystem properly. Gatsby cannot process your images if the filesystem is not set. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Ive got it working using code above but it loops for the correct number of images but only displays the first image from the array. Do you know why this might be? - https://imgur.com/a/MAdvbvT

Comment: Nice! I'm glad to help. Without seeing the code it's impossible to guess, maybe you are missing the `key` attribute.